# Java: ByteArray to positive number and vice versa conversion

Tags: java, arrays, numbers, biginteger

I'm looking for a way, how to reversibly convert a byte[] of an arbitrary length to **positive** number (String representation in numbers).

**BigInteger offers a solution:**

```
byte[] originalBytes = ...
String string = new BigInteger(originalBytes).toString();
...
byte[] decodedBytes = new BigInteger(string).toByteArray();
```

However, I'm not sure how to get gracefully rid of negative values (or where to store the sign) and keep the process reversible.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can keep the same numbers but remove negative values.  You could add 127 to all the numbers, but obviously all the numbers will be different.  The process will be reversible though.

Comment: Clarify "get gracefully rid of negative values"

Comment: @Tron Are you saying the bytes you receive don't have the two's complement form, in other words you're working with unsigned bytes? Could you expand your question with a simple example of the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** just replace

```
String string = new BigInteger(originalBytes).toString();
```

with

```
String string = new BigInteger(1, originalBytes).toString();
```

The `1,` signals that the passed array represents a positive number ([signum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) = 1)

**Original:**

You can just prefix the array with a zero byte:

```
byte[] original = new byte[] { (byte) 255 };

System.out.println(new BigInteger(original).toString()); // prints "-1"

byte[] paddedCopy = new byte[original.length + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
    paddedCopy[i + 1] = original[i];
}
System.out.println(new BigInteger(paddedCopy).toString()); // prints "255"
```

This will essentially nullify the sign bit, making the number unsigned.